# NumPy: Limited cumulative sum

Tags: python, numpy

Is there some way to avoid the `for` loop in this code:

```
X = numpy array ~8000 long
running_total = 0
for x in X:
    this_step = min(x, running_total)
    running_total += this_step
```

In words, that's calculating a cumulative sum of a series where the difference between samples is limited to the previous value of the cumulative sum.  Is there some way to do this using numpy's element-wise operations?  Or should I be looking to write a C function if I care how fast this runs?

**Edit**  Obviously I've not made myself clear.  My attempt to simplify the code above seems to have caused more confusion than anything else.  Here's something closer to the actual code:

```
monthly_income = numpy array ~ 8000 long
monthly_expenditure = numpy array ~ 8000 long
running_credit = numpy.zeros(len(monthly_income) + 1)
monthly_borrowing = numpy.zeros(len(monthly_income))
for index, i, e in zip(range(len(monthly_income)), monthly_income, monthly_expenditure):
    assets_used = max(0, e - i)
    assets_used = min(assets_used, running_credit[index])
    monthly_borrowing[index] = max(0, e - i - running_credit[index])
    running_credit[index+1] += max(0, i - e) - assets_used
```

The point is that `running_index[index+1]` depends on `assets_used` at sample `index`, which depends on `running_credit[index]`.  Doing this in a Python loop is slow - in a function which does many similar calculations on the same input arrays using NumPy operations, the above loop takes over 80% of the execution time.  But I can't see a way of doing the above operation without a for loop.

So is there some way of doing this kind of iterative operation in NumPy without a for loop?  Or do I need to write a C function if I want this to run fast?

Comment: If `this_step` is nonnegative, `running_total` is always 0. Actually, I can't find usage of `x` and `y` inside a for loop and seems either your code or description cannot explain the other not very well.

Comment: Sorry, it's edited down from larger code.  Fixed now.

Comment: I'm not sure your code matches your explanation. In particular, `running_total` will always be non-positive according to your code.

Comment: Also, your series will diverge very fast and if X does not quickly decrease (towards large negative values) than you can actually get the result by `X[j]*2**(len(X)-(j+1))` where j is the index of the first negative value

Comment: Tom, perhaps you meant `running_total = X[0]` and `for x in X[1:]:`, and you assume that `X[0]` is not zero, and `X[k] >= 0` for k in [0, 1, ..., len(X)-1].

Comment: Please show a, short, example of the input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest quick-fix for this kind of problem i find is to use numba. E.g.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

def cumsumcapped(X):
    running_total = 0
    for x in X:
        this_step = min(x, running_total)
        running_total += this_step

@jit
def cumsumcappedjit(X):
    running_total = 0
    for x in X:
        this_step = min(x, running_total)
        running_total += this_step  

X = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10000)

In [5]: %timeit cumsumcapped(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit stack.cumsumcappedjit(X)
The slowest run took 170143.03 times longer than the fastest. This     could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 587 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but guessing from your explanation (assuming x is nonnegative)

```
X = [1 ... 999]
running_total = X[0]
for x in X[1:]:
    this_step = min(x, running_total)
    running_total += this_step
```

Comment: The question was, "Is there some way to do this using numpy's element-wise operations?"  You're still using a for-loop.

Comment: *Next* `running_total` is undetermined unless *previous* one is calculated. So is `this_step`. Element-wise operation is valid when each element is untouched by others.